# Bootstrap model scroll issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

[This is my website.](http://testenv.jobjobsearch.net/US/)

I place a bootstrap modal displayed when clicking the icon in the search input box (search, location). But when the model is displayed the background is shifted to the left since the scroll bar for the page is disappearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could overwrite the css from bootstrap which is causing the scrollbar to be hidden:

Change:

```
.modal-open {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

To:

```
.modal-open {
   overflow: auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert your code in this function which will be triggered by opening of the modal window:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  // your jQuery code goes here
})
```